# Android. TextView. Last visible character of the text

Tags: android, string, kotlin, textview, mobile-development

I have a TextView match parented for whole screen, and a text appended on it.
For example, the Raven poem:

```
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
"'Tis some visiter," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door—
Only this, and nothing more." etc etc etc...
```

I can't see it all on my phone screen.
So the question:
How can I get the index of the last visible character of the text?
[How can I see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS6k1.png)

Comment: This is probably answered somewhere here already, but I couldn't find anything relevant, so: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r3-794zuR4qP-8uy6CARtZy8Mpq9c7cm/view?usp=sharing. It's unclear how you wanted to handle a partially-visible line. That example grabs the last fully visible line, but you can fiddle with as you need. I wouldn't try to use that on `EditText`s without further testing, but it should work well on regular `TextView`s.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it will just return whitespace if a blank line is the last fully "visible" one, since it wasn't clear how to handle that, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want index then use,

```
val poem = "hello"
val lastCharacterIndex = poem.toCharArray().size - 1
```

If you want the Character at that index then use,

```
val character = poem.toCharArray()[index]
```

But I think you want to make your text view scrollable so that you can see the whole poem. Then you can use ScrollView as parent tag in XML then wrap the text view inside it.

Comment: Actually I want TextView return the last visible char index (not last at all).

And ScrollView shouldn't be used.

Comment: @eyelog last visible char? or the string ?

Comment: OP's question is pretty clear that he/she wants last visible character not the last character in physical way.

Comment: The index of last visible char of textView.text. String or CharSequence - doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Many many thanks for [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) here the answer:

```
fun TextView.getLastVisibleCharacter(): Int {
        val layoutBottom = height + scrollY - totalPaddingTop - totalPaddingBottom
        val bottomLine = layout.getLineForVertical(layoutBottom)
        val lastWhollyVisibleLineNumber =
            if (layout.getLineBottom(bottomLine) > layoutBottom) bottomLine - 1
            else bottomLine
        return layout.getLineVisibleEnd(lastWhollyVisibleLineNumber) - 1
    }
```